# MySQL AND OR with multiple values and columns. Trying to understand MySQL logic

Tags: mysql

Trying to understand `MySQL` logic

```
| RecordDay | RecordMonth | RecordYear
----------------------------------------
  02        |   04        |   2013    
  03        |   05        |   2014
  04        |   06        |   2015
```

My logic. If I want to see all records except records where `RecordDay` = 02 and `RecordMonth` = 04 and `RecordYear` = 2013 (do not want to see records where date is 02.April, 2013), I write query like `WHERE CAST(RecordDay AS UNSIGNED) != ? AND CAST(RecordMonth AS UNSIGNED) != ? AND CAST(RecordYear AS UNSIGNED) != ?`. Like if I want to see, I write the same query with `=`. For `=` query works, but for `!=` does not.

Now understand that with the query MySQL goes through columns and rows and excludes results where `RecordDay` = 02, `RecordMonth` = 04, `RecordYear` = 2013. With the query I as if tell I do not want to see results where...

See that this query `WHERE (CAST(RecordDay AS UNSIGNED) != ? OR CAST(RecordMonth AS UNSIGNED) != ? OR CAST(RecordYear AS UNSIGNED) != ?)` works. But do not understand why it works.

What does MySQL do? Goes through columns and rows, find row where `RecordDay` = 02, then check what values are in `RecordMonth` and `RecordYear`...

Found explanation

`The AND operator displays a record if both the first condition AND the second condition are true.` In the same way should be `The AND operator **does not** display a record if both the first condition AND the second condition are true.`

The OR operator displays a record if either the first condition OR the second condition is true.

And how with `>` `REGEXP`-contains?

Mess in my head....

Comment: Have you thought of using DATETIME field, like `2013-04-02`?

Comment: If you've answered your own question, please submit an answer.

Comment: I know, but decided that I need separate day|month|year. Because if many rows with dates, it is faster input. Or I need the separated input to convert to `DATETIME`. Possibly I will do that if will not understand MySQL logic

Comment: Yes your explanation is right. but what you want. and what do you mean byyour statement **And how with > REGEXP-contains?**.

Comment: With `>` mean if date is after input date. `REGEXP` if date contains certain date. I mean may be also unexpected results... I need to filter results based on day, month, year and want to understand MySQL behavior, to get results, I have expected

Comment: This isn't something particular to SQL. This is just boolean logic. The opposite of `if a=b and c=d` is not `if a!=b and c!=d`. It's either `if a!=b or c!=d` or `if !(a=b and c=d)`.

Comment: @Ollie Jones. Seems understand how `AND` works. But do not understand logic with `OR`. From my opinion illogical. Just need to remember such behavior...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions for how to handle your date information.

Pulling out all your data is simple.

```
SELECT RecordDay, RecordMonth, RecordYear
  FROM t
```

Forget about the casting.  MySQL knows to do that.

Then, suppose you only want to *include* records with the year 2013.  You do this.

```
SELECT RecordDay, RecordMonth, RecordYear
  FROM t
 WHERE RecordYear = 2013
```

Easy.

Now, supposing you want to include records with year / month /day = 2013 / 4 / 2.  You do this, using `WHERE` / `AND` because you wish for all the conditions to be satisfied in order to select records.

```
SELECT RecordDay, RecordMonth, RecordYear
  FROM t
 WHERE RecordYear = 2013
   AND RecordMonth = 4
   AND RecordDay = 2
```

That grabs the one record from your table.  See here.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c75d6/14/0

Next, you are looking to *exclude* rather than *include* the records that meet all three of those criteria (`WHERE` ... `AND` ... `AND` ...) This little bit of logic does the trick.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c75d6/15/0

```
SELECT RecordDay, RecordMonth, RecordYear
  FROM t
 WHERE NOT (
                 RecordYear = 2013
             AND RecordMonth = 4
             AND RecordDay = 2
            )
```

Now, according to the rules of Boolean algebra, you can do simple transformations on expressions. Aristotle, William of Ockham, and DeMorgan figured this out. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws .  For example

```
  NOT (a AND b AND c)
```

can be transformed to

```
 (NOT a) OR (NOT b) OR (NOT c)
```

In SQL, that's written like this. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c75d6/16/0

```
SELECT RecordDay, RecordMonth, RecordYear
  FROM t
 WHERE NOT(RecordYear = 2013)
    OR NOT(RecordMonth = 4)
    OR NOT(RecordDay = 2)
```

Finally, we can rewrite `NOT(RecordYear = 2013)` as `RecordYear != 2013`. Doing that we get this:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c75d6/17/0

```
SELECT RecordDay, RecordMonth, RecordYear
  FROM t
 WHERE RecordYear != 2013
    OR RecordMonth != 4
    OR RecordDay != 2
```

This is saying, select any rows meeting one or more of these three inequality conditions.

At its heart, the `WHERE` part of the SQL language is a Boolean expression engine used for manipulating sets of rows.  There are all kinds of ways to write Boolean expressions, and many of them work in SQL.

Finally, do consider using real dates. SQL has lots of good stuff to handle them. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c75d6/9/0

Notice this little bit of SQL code.

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) RecordDate
```

This converts your discrete day/month/year date representation into a `DATE` object, which is really quite handy for all sorts of things like ordering dates from latest to earliest...

```
 ORDER BY RecordDate DESC
```

You can do date arithmetic. For example, you can fetch records from the eight days leading up to April 2, like so.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c75d6/13/0

```
 WHERE RecordDate >= '2013-04-02' - INTERVAL 8 DAY
   AND RecordDate <= '2013-04-02'
```

Comment: Thanks! This `SELECT CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) RecordDate` is very good advice for me. Did not know it. It makes all much simplier.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need `or` instead of `and` if you reverse the logic, or you can use `not` to reverse the entire expression.

So you can use the comparison to see if the row matches the date and then use `NOT` to fetch not those, but all other rows.

```
WHERE NOT (day = 2 AND month = 4 AND year = 2013)
```

Which is basically *) the same as:

```
WHERE day != 2 OR month != 4 OR year != 2013
```

After all, as soon as *either* day *or* month *or* year is different, it's not 2 april 2013 anymore. And as soon as day *and* month *and* year match the values of the date, the it's that date, otherwise it's not. So in natural language you can also see this difference between *and* and *or*, as long as you are very precise in your description, which we humans are usually not, because most of the meaning we understand through context.

Boolean logic is actually one of the main reasons why programmers cannot communicate with 'normal' people. ;)

*) It's not entirely the same when it comes to rows containing `NULL` for any of the values, but that's a different story altogether.